# How do I call a function name that is stored in a hash in Perl?

Tags: perl, syntax, reference, attributes, moose

I'm sure this is covered in the documentation somewhere but I have been unable to find it... I'm looking for the syntactic sugar that will make it possible to call a method on a class whose name is stored in a hash (as opposed to a simple scalar):

```
use strict; use warnings;

package Foo;
sub foo { print "in foo()\n" }

package main;
my %hash = (func => 'foo');

Foo->$hash{func};
```

If I copy `$hash{func}` into a scalar variable first, then I can call `Foo->$func` just fine... but what is missing to enable `Foo->$hash{func}` to work?

(EDIT: I don't mean to do anything special by calling a method on class `Foo` -- this could just as easily be a blessed object (and in my actual code it is); it was just easier to write up a self-contained example using a class method.)

EDIT 2: Just for completeness re the comments below, this is what I'm actually doing (this is in a library of Moose attribute sugar, created with [Moose::Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose::Exporter)):

```
# adds an accessor to a sibling module
sub foreignTable
{
    my ($meta, $table, %args) = @_;

    my $class = 'MyApp::Dir1::Dir2::' . $table;
    my $dbAccessor = lcfirst $table;

    eval "require $class" or do { die "Can't load $class: $@" };

    $meta->add_attribute(
        $table,
        is => 'ro',
        isa => $class,
        init_arg => undef,  # don't allow in constructor
        lazy => 1,
        predicate => 'has_' . $table,
        default => sub {
            my $this = shift;
            $this->debug("in builder for $class");

            ### here's the line that uses a hash value as the method name
            my @args = ($args{primaryKey} => $this->${\$args{primaryKey}});
            push @args, ( _dbObject => $this->_dbObject->$dbAccessor )
                if $args{fkRelationshipExists};

            $this->debug("passing these values to $class -> new: @args");
            $class->new(@args);
        },
    );
}
```

I've replaced the marked line above with this:

```
        my $pk_accessor = $this->meta->find_attribute_by_name($args{primaryKey})->get_read_method_ref;
        my @args = ($args{primaryKey} => $this->$pk_accessor);
```

PS. I've just noticed that this same technique (using the Moose meta class to look up the coderef rather than assuming its naming convention) *cannot* also be used for predicates, as [Class::MOP::Attribute](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::MOP::Attribute) does not have a similar `get_predicate_method_ref` accessor. :(

Comment: I don't think that is possible due to Perl's parsing order. Why do you not want copy $hash{func} into a scalar first?

Comment: No particular reason except it seems unnecessary, and this was an interesting puzzle that stumped me. I did not believe that simply because I did not know the answer that there was no answer. :)  (tl;dr version: because I'm curious!)

Comment: Er, it seems to me that if you're using Moose, then you're still going about it the wrong way.  One of the features of Moose is the meta object model that it's built on...I have a feeling that there's a method you can call to look up the actual sub by string name, which you could then call, instead of using bare strings.  I don't know it off the top of my head, though...

Comment: @RobertP: I think you mean `my $reader_ref = $this->meta->find_attribute_by_name($fieldname)->get_read_method_ref;` (see Class::MOP::Class and Class::MOP::Attribute), but all this does is get around the possibility that the reader is named something different than the attribute name.

Comment: PS. tomorrow I'll post the *actual* code that I was dealing with so we can critique it more :) there may indeed be a better way of doing what I was doing. It is mostly orthogonal to my curiosity over this particular question of syntax, however.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so.  For others who look at this piece, once you have that, you can just do `$this->$reader_ref()` and it will be way cleaner than the by-string-name version.  PBP has a good explanation why using a subref is the better way of doing it, if anyone is interested.

Comment: As a historical footnote, I should note now that all the code above got nuked from orbit in a subsequent refactoring.  1. it's crazy to attempt to reimplement an ORM when there are many good ones to choose from, and 2. in Moose, it's better to call `$attr->set_value($instance, $value)` rather than making assumptions about what an accessor is called.

Comment: I assume you meant Moose::Exporter in "Edit 2".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Foo->${\$hash{func}};
```

But for clarity, I'd probably still write it as:

```
my $method = $hash{func};
Foo->$method;
```

Comment: Simple *and* obvious; I love it!

Comment: I understand the first dollar sign. But what I don't get is the backslash.

Comment: @Manni: The ${...} is parsed as a scalar dereference rather than a disambiguation because the contents aren't a literal string. The backslash is to create a reference to the value of $hash{func}.

Comment: Manni's comment is an excellent example of why you shouldn't use this construct in production code. It's not as simple as it appears at first glance. How it works (and by extension, what it does when you return to it a year from now) can be cryptic even to experienced Perl programmers. It's much better write *clear* code than to write *clever* code: `my $method = $hash{func}; Foo->$method()`.

Comment: I mostly agree with Michael, so I've updated my answer to reflect that. I've never actually used the shorter way except to see that it works, but I've used the longer way many times.

Comment: Oh interesting. Is the Foo->$method syntax documented in the official doc? I've looked around and can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you are storing subroutine names instead of the references to code?

e.g.

```
use strict; use warnings;

package Foo;
sub foo { print "in foo()\n" }

package main;
my %hash = (func => \&Foo::foo);

$hash{func}->();
```

You won't be passing the class name, but if that's important to you, you can use something like

```
my %hash = ( func => sub { return Foo->foo(@_) } );
```

Comment: Yes, because the sub names correspond to attribute names taken from Moose objects.

Comment: I've edited my question to indicate that `Foo` could either be a class name or a blessed object.

Comment: You don't want a sub reference because that breaks inheritance.

Comment: So, instead of a sub reference use a closure over the methodname, like my %hash = (func => foo); my %method_hash = map { my $meth = $hash{$_}; $_ => sub { Foo->$meth } } keys %hash; $method_hash{func}->();

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [UNIVERSAL's](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html) *can* method?  You should be able to implement something like this:

```
## untested
if ( my $code = $object->can( $hash{func} ) ) {
    $object->$code();
}
```

I made a useless, one-line example to demonstrate:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -le 'my %h = ( f => "Dump" ); my $o = Data::Dumper->new( [qw/1 2 3/] ); my $ref = $o->can( $h{f} ); print $o->$ref()'
```

Comment: Yes, but again this is a diversion away from my original question about how to use a hash value as a method name (which runrig answered). `can` in this case is a less perfect solution than the one I outlined in a question edit, as it makes assumptions about the naming of a Moose reader.