# How to access a sub through symbol table for main:: and name of sub in a scalar variable

Tags: perl, syntax

Suppose I have a function `foo` (or `::foo`, or `main::foo` if you prefer), and I define

```
use strict;
my $sub_name = 'foo';
```

I want to invoke `foo` indirectly, as "the function whose name is stored in `$sub_name`".  (For the sake of this example, assume that the invocation should pass the list `1, 2, 3` as arguments.)

I know that there's a way to do this by working with the symbol table for `main::` directly, treating it like a hash-like data structure.

This symbol-table incantation is what I'm looking for.

I've done this sort of thing many times before, but I have not programmed Perl in many years, and I no longer remember the incantation.

(I'd prefer to do this without having to resort to `no strict`, but no biggie if that's not possible.)

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1915616/5830574

Comment: @PerlDuck: I saw that thread, but I don't see the answer to my question in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd simply use a symbolic reference.

```
my $sub = \&$qualified_sub_name;    # \&$symbol is except from strict 'refs'.

$sub->()
```

But you requested that we avoid using symbolic reference. That's way too complex. (It's also might not handle weird but legit  misuse of colons.)

```
my $pkg = \%::;
my $sub_name = $qualified_sub_name;
$pkg = $pkg->{$1} while $sub_name =~ s/^(.*?::)//sg;
my $sub = $pkg->{$sub_name};
$sub = *{ $pkg->{$sub_name} }{CODE}
   if ref(\$sub) eq 'GLOB';  # Skip if glob optimized away.

$sub->()
```

Comment: Your answer jogged my memory.  What I was looking for was simply the expression `*{$::{'foo'}}{CODE}(1,2,3)`.  Thanks!

Comment: @ikegami No, perl optimizes the case of a simple sub `foo` if no other slots (such as `$foo` or `@foo`) exist. It'll store a coderef directly in the symbol table.

Comment: The other interesting case is constants: `perl -wE 'use constant foo => 42; say $::{foo}'` - `SCALAR(0x3a9808)`. Not a mess, just standard Perl behavior.

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, the optimization is broken in non-`main` packages, but it's currently being fixed in blead (and breaking broken modules elsewhere).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [can](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html):

```
my $sub_name = 'foo';
my $coderef = main->can($sub_name);
$coderef->(@args);
```

As others have mentioned, you should note that this can return also methods like "can" or "isa".
Also, if `$sub_name` contains `Some::Module::subname`, this will also be called.

If you're not sure what's in `$sub_name`, you probably want a different approach.
Use this only if you have control over `$sub_name` and it can contain only expected values. (I assumed this, that's why I wrote this answer.)

Comment: This may return unexpected results if `$sub_name` is e.g. `"isa"`.

Comment: The OP asked how to perform a sub call, not a method call (which you did wrong anyway!!). Your approach can lead to the wrong sub being called.

Comment: ikegami: `$coderef->()` is a sub call, not a method call.

Comment: Yes, but your code is not the same as `main::foo()`, the sub call the OP requested. You partially implemented a method call instead.

Comment: I agree that it's not the same in all circumstances, but if the subname is just `foo`, and `main` does not inherit from another package that implements `foo`, then it's just the same as `main::foo()`

Comment: @ikegami: Even though I was indeed asking for `*{$::{foo}}{CODE}`, AFAICT, `main->can('foo')` yields exactly the same entity, so I don't understand your objection.

Comment: @kjo, Quite the contrary, and as I already said, it does NOT always yield the same result. `can` performs a method search.