# How do I implement a dispatch table in a Perl OO module?

Tags: perl, oop

I want to put some subs that are within an OO package into an array - also within the package - to use as a dispatch table. Something like this

```
package Blah::Blah;

use fields 'tests';

sub new {
    my($class )= @_;

    my $self = fields::new($class);

    $self->{'tests'} = [
                         $self->_sub1
                        ,$self->_sub2
                       ];
    return $self;
}

_sub1 { ... };
_sub2 { ... };
```

I'm not entirely sure on the syntax for this?

```
$self->{'tests'} = [
                         $self->_sub1
                        ,$self->_sub2
                       ];
```

or

```
$self->{'tests'} = [
                         \&{$self->_sub1}
                        ,\&{$self->_sub2}
                       ];
```

or

```
$self->{'tests'} = [
                         \&{_sub1}
                        ,\&{_sub2}
                       ];
```

I don't seem to be able to get this to work within an OO package, whereas it's quite straightforward in a procedural fashion, and I haven't found any examples for OO.

Any help is much appreciated,
Iain

Comment: Thanks very much for all the answers. I've set brian d foy's answer as the accepted one because I tried all the methods and that's the closest to the one I've finished with, but I've learnt so much from each of the answers and each has definite advantages that it was difficult to choose.

I also didn't expect to get such good and quick answers to what (I considered) a reasonably less obvious sort of question. I feel quite tardy now! :) Stackoverflow is a really good site.

Comment: I should also mention that I talk quite a bit about this sort of stuff in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242), and you might also check out [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I implement a dispatch table in a Perl OO module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791833/how-do-i-implement-a-dispatch-table-in-a-perl-oo-module)

Comment: I talk quite a bit about this sort of thing in _Mastering Perl_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although [Robert P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791833/how-do-i-implement-a-dispatch-table-in-a-perl-oo-module/2791880#2791880)'s answer might work for you, it has the problem of fixing the dispatch very early in the process. I tend to resolve the methods as late as I can, so I would leave the things in the `tests` array as method names until you want to use them:

```
 $self->{tests} = [
     qw( _sub1 _sub2 )
     ];
```

The strength of a dynamic language is that you can wait as long as you like to decide what's going to happen.

When you want to run them, you can go through the same process that Robert already noted. I'd add an interface to it though:

```
  foreach my $method_name ( $obj->get_test_methods )
      {
      $obj->$method_name();
      }
```

That might even be better as not tying the test to an existing method name:

```
  foreach my $method_name ( $obj->get_test_methods )
      {
      $obj->run_test_named( $method_name );
      }
```

That `run_test_named` could then be your dispatcher, and it can be very flexible:

```
 sub run_test_named
      {
      my( $self, $name ) = @_;

      # do anything you want, like in Robert's answer
      }
```

Some things you might want to do:

- Run a method on an object
- Pass the object as an argument to something else
- Temporarily override a test
- Do nothing
- etc, etc

When you separate what you decide to do from its implementation, you have a lot more freedom. Not only that, the next time you call the same test name, you can do something different.

Comment: To solve the timeliness issue you mention, an alternative would be to simply make the {test} a subroutine itself, that returns a ref, and then you could get it at exactly the time you need it: `sub tests { return [ $self->can('_sub1'), $self->can('_sub2') ] }` and then use it like `for $tn (0..$#{$self->tests()}) { ... }`.

Answer (score 11):

Your friend is [`can`](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html).  It returns a reference to the subroutine if it exists, null otherwise.  It even does it correctly walking up the OO chain.

```
$self->{tests} = [
    $self->can('_sub1'),
    $self->can('_sub2'),
];

# later

for $tn (0..$#{$self->{tests}}) {
    ok defined $self->{tests}[$tn], "Function $tn is available.";
}

# and later

my $ref = $self->{tests}[0];
$self->$ref(@args1);
$ref = $self->{tests}[1];
$self->$ref(@args2);
```

Or, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804109/how-do-i-use-an-index-in-an-array-reference-as-a-method-reference-in-perl) question (which happens to be a variation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836178/how-do-i-call-a-function-name-that-is-stored-in-a-hash-in-perl) question), you can call it directly:

```
$self->${\$self->{tests}[0]}(@args1);
$self->${\$self->{tests}[1]}(@args1);
```

Note that the `\` gives us a reference to a the subref, which then gets dereferenced by the `${}` after `$self->`.  Whew!

To solve the timeliness issue brain d foy mentions, an alternative would be to simply make the {test} a subroutine itself, that returns a ref, and then you could get it at exactly the time you need it:

```
sub tests {
    return [ 
        $self->can('_sub1'),
        $self->can('_sub2')
    ];
}
```

and then use it:

```
for $tn (0..$#{$self->tests()}) {
   ...
}
```

Of course, if you have to iterate over the refs anyway, you might as well just go straight for passing the reference out:

```
for my $ref (0..$#{$self->tests()}) {
    $self->$ref(@args);
}
```

Comment: I'd filter out the undefs earlier so you don't have to think about them at the higher level.

Comment: Agreed, if this was called in production code.  My check there was if it was being used in a test suite (say, being built with [`Test::More`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::More).)

Answer (score 6):

```
use lib Alpha;

my $foo = Alpha::Foo->new; # indirect object syntax is deprecated

$foo->bar();

my %disp_table = ( bar => sub { $foo->bar() } );

$disp_table{bar}->(); # call it
```

You need a closure because you want to turn a method call into an ordinary subroutine call, so you have to capture the object you're calling the method on.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a closure. You could have a dispatch table of method names and do `my $meth = $table{bar}; $foo->$meth;` Or you could be silly and do `$foo->${ \$table{bar} }`

Comment: @friedo, it depends on what sort of dispatch table you want.  If you want to encapsulate both a method name and an object in a single entry, then you need a closure.  If you're ok with passing the object separately, then you have more options.

Comment: You might want the closure to pass on the arguments too: sub { $foo->bar(@_) }

Comment: @Grant McLean, obviously that depends on the method you're calling.  His example indicated `bar` has no parameters, so I didn't bother passing any.

Comment: indirect object syntax is not deprecated, just discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to do this.  Your third approach is closest.  That will store a reference to the two subs in the array.  Then when you want to call them, you have to be sure to pass them an object as their first argument.

Is there a reason you are using the `use fields` construct?

if you want to create self contained test subs, you could do it this way:

```
$$self{test} = [ 
     map {
         my $code = $self->can($_); # retrieve a reference to the method
         sub {                  # construct a closure that will call it
             unshift @_, $self; # while passing $self as the first arg
             goto &$code;   # goto jumps to the method, to keep 'caller' working
         }    
     } qw/_sub1 _sub2/                  
 ];
```

and then to call them

```
for (@{ $$self{test} }) {
    eval {$_->(args for the test); 1} or die $@;
}
```

Comment: In general, storing the code refs with `can` is better than putting a wrapper around them.  Its a bit faster and it doesn't add a level to the call stack which may be important (think about carp and croak).  You can also use the code refs on any instance, the original instance is not hard coded.  The advantage (or hard to debug action-at-a-distance) to your technique is should the inheritance of `_sub1` and `_sub2` change between storing them and calling them it will call the new methods.

Comment: thanks, i agree that `->can` is better, i've updated my answer to use it.  `goto` as well for caller.  while slower, it seemed to me from the OP that they were looking for a way to package up the tests, and Robert already gave the direct answer.